# Does Bruteforce matching work with FREAK descriptors?

Tags: java, android, opencv

I've been making an application on the smartphone for Android, where 2 images can be compared (one on the SD card, one from the camera). There I use a FREAK descriptor on a limited amount of keypoints (i filtered out the 500 best ones according to the response). When I try to match it with BRUTEFORCE_SL2, it gives back 0 matches.

Is this because FREAK and Bruteforce don't work well together? Or did I do something wrong in the code?

Matching happens with

```
MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();

            matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_SL2);
            matcher.match(descriptors,descriptors1,matches);
            MatOfDMatch goedematches = new MatOfDMatch();

            double max_dist = 0;
            double min_dist = 100;
            //if (descriptors.cols() == descriptors1.cols())
            //{
            for( int i = 0; i < descriptors.rows(); i++ )
            { double dist = matches.toArray()[i].distance;
              if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
              if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
            }
            // should only draw good matches
           for( int i = 0; i < descriptors.rows(); i++ )
            {  MatOfDMatch temp = new MatOfDMatch();
               if( matches.toArray()[i].distance < 3*min_dist )
               {   temp.fromArray(matches.toArray()[i]);
                   goedematches.push_back(temp); 
                   }        
           // }
            }

           Log.d("LOG!", "Number of good matches= " + goedematches.size());
```

When I just do the

```
matcher.match(descriptors,descriptors1,matches);
```

and read out the matches with

```
Log.d("LOG!", "Number of good matches= " + matches.size());
```

I get about 450 even if I take a picture of something that doesn't even look like my image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, FREAK creates **binary descriptors**. Therefore, you should use the **Hamming distance** instead of the Euclidean one (which makes no sense here):

```
matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);
```

The Hamming distance will actually count the number of bits that differ from one descriptor to the other.

Then, it is important to know that the matcher only finds the *best correspondence* **for each** descriptor you have in `descriptors`. So if you get less matches than expected, you need to look at the steps before (features detection and descriptors extraction).

**EDIT:** Even though the images might be completely different, you will get the best match for each descriptor (even if this match is actually wrong). The sample codes in the documentation offer to filter out the worse matches by testing if the distance is greater than `3*min_dist`. But this won't eliminate the wrong matches! Consider having two completely different images; the algorithm will find the `best` possible matches for them, even though in reality those are all wrong matches... If you really want to keep "correct" matches, you will have to use a more advanced filtering technique (but this is another problem).

Last thing I want to mention (for the comprehension of the matcher) is that `matcher.match()` is not symmetric:

```
matcher.match(descriptors,descriptors1,matches);
```

will find, *for each descriptor in `descriptors`, the best correspondence in `descriptors1`*. It might be the case that the inverse is not true (you might try it to convince yourself).

Here is a more detailed example of what I mean by "not symmetric": Suppose you have a descriptor `Ai` on image `A` and you match image `A` to image `B`. You will get `Bi`, which will be the best correspondence in `B` for `Ai`.

Now, if you match image `B` to image `A`, you will get the best correspondence in `A` for `Bi`. But there possibly exist an `Aj`, different from `Ai`, which is more similar to `Bi` than `Aj`.

In this case, matching `A` to `B` will give the correspondence `Ai <-> Bi` when matching `B` to `A` will give the correspondence `Bi <-> Aj` which is clearly not the same.

Comment: What do you mean with the last sentence? Thank you for the information, i'll try the Hamming out and check my results

Comment: Yes it is, and i'm been trying hamming but goedematches.size() gives back weird results. I get more good matches with an image that has nothing to do with the original image, than one that is almost identical to the original image.

Comment: I modified my answer again. Just try to draw `matches` and `goedematches` to see if some of the matches are correct. It is not unusual to have wrong matches (and those need to be filtered out), but you should also get correct matches (this is even more true if both images are almost identical).